# is laughing in ridicule of haram things seen as haram?

Tags: halal-haram

If someone were to laugh at someone committing aspostasy then returning back and forth because it seems stupid, is it haram?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there should be a clear distinction between humor and haram. As muslims we are charged with defending the faith, I do not see where it would be pleasing, nor give a good perspective of the faith, (in spite of personal sense of humor) to give any type of humor towards that which is haram. Especially if we could be guiding a brother or sister,  but Allah knows best!